# Jquery - Button does not fire properly with class

Tags: jquery

Here is a sample code:

```js
$("#item > button:not(.finished)").on("click", function() {
  console.log("fired");
  $(this).addClass("finished");
})

$("#item > button.finished").on("click", function() {
  console.log("finished");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">
  <button type="button" class="">Text</button>
</div>
```

For some reason it always logs "fired. Even if the class is added. What am I not seeing??

Note: button is **NOT** dynamic.

Comment: Events are bound to the nodes matching the selector when the code is run, changing the classes after the events are attached makes no difference to that event-binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why your code is not working as you expect is pointed out by David Thomas in the comment

> Events are bound to the nodes matching the selector when the code is
>   run, changing the classes after the events are attached makes no
>   difference to that event-binding

that's why you always see `fired` logged to the console

Here's a simplified version of your code that works as you expect it to.

```js
$("#item > button").on("click", function(e) {

  if(!(e.target.classList.contains('finished'))) {
      $(e.target).addClass("finished");
      console.log("fired");
  } else {
      console.log("finished");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">
  <button type="button" class="">Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful and comprehensive. Very much appreciated. Thank you.